# How do i duplicate this marble background.

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I want to duplicate this marble background. heres how its supposed to look [image]

Here's my attempt 
[image]

Comment: Yours looks great. The original looks like a stucco wall.

Answer (score 1):

Your version looks more like marble than the other one.
However, I would recommend actually obtaining the real marble repeating textures **made from real marble.** It's not expensive and you can even get a free trial for the low resolution ones that you can use commercially just for signing up.

This may not be necessary to you but they were originally made for 3D programs so they have extra files to reflect light bounces and stuff like normals, glossy, etc... You don't need those extra files but if you know anything about 3D modeling programs it can help your mock up look even more realistic.[image]

Even if you are not using these for 3D modeling its very useful to have repeating textures and you can use it to guide yourself in making your own.

https://www.poliigon.com/search/recent/narrow/list/marble?preview=Cube

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you duplicate it by any means. Your own attempt seems much more a real thing than the shapes behind the red advertisement. Only an experienced person who knows the stones possibly could tell, if the "own attempt" were a homemade fake and what is the difference.

Besides it's often illegal to make duplicates of pieces of artwork.

Answer (score 0):

Clone some parts of the stone for multiplying the marble effect. Works same for clouds, etc.

https://www.thoughtco.com/photoshop-clone-stamp-tool-tutorial-1697534